# Express.js: respond with image file instead of binary file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

In express, I'm trying to respond with an image to a React request, however, I get the image binary file instead of the image file.

I tried using res.sendFile and res.download, but they send the binary file. I also tried res.attachment but it works inconsistently, and somehow makes the respond pending.

I tried specifying the file type with res.type("image/jpeg"), but it doesn't make a difference.

```
router.get("/photo", (req, res) => {

  res.type("image/jpeg");
  res.sendFile("/absolute/path/image.jpg");

});
```

I'm expecting an image file with normal properties of name, size, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the distinction you are drawing between an "image file" and an "image binary file" is misleading you. All bitmap image files are encoded in binary (or, on rare occasions, base64), so I don't think that gets to the root of your problem.

**`res.sendFile` should work just fine. The problem is in your client-side JavaScript.**

To display image data in the browser, you will ultimately have to use `canvas` or `img` HTML elements. The easiest way to asynchronously load an image in your app would be to update the `src` attribute of an `img` element that already exists in the DOM to the address of the image and let the browser handle the loading for you.

However, if you want to manipulate the image data prior to loading it to an `img` or `canvas` element, I would recommend using the `FileReader` API, as opposed to manually parsing the binary.

**The key step with this approach is to set the response data type to "blob" when you make your `get` request**

The `blob` data type references the binary image file, but allows you to use the browser's built-in `File` interface.

The code below requests an image file as a blob and then converts the blob into a base64 encoded data url that you can use as the `src` attribute of an `img` element or load to a `canvas`.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = "blob";
xhr.onload = function(event) {
fileToDataUrl(event.target.response, function(result){
            console.log(result);
    });
};
xhr.open('GET', "https://i.imgur.com/7VhSUEH.jpg", true);
xhr.send();


function fileToDataUrl(fileObj, callback) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("load", function() {
    console.log("result")
        callback(reader.result);
    }, false);
    reader.readAsDataURL(fileObj);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Neil for clearing things up. The File interface is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const fs = require("fs");

router.get("/photo", (req, res) => {
    fs.readFile("/absolute/path/image.jpg", function(err, data) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.set("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
        return res.status(200).end(data, 'binary');;
    });
});
```

Comment: What should I use as a method for specifying the file path? I added res.sendFile("path/image.jpg"), but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Try this new approach.

Comment: If this works please tell me and mark it as correct answer =D

Answer (score 0):

```
var filename = __dirname+ imagePath; 
var readStream = fs.createReadStream(filename);
readStream.on('open', function () {
  readStream.pipe(res);
});
readStream.on('error', function(err) {
  res.end(err);
});
```

Please don't forget to put fs dependency